# .htaccess to remove https if subdomain of URL

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https, subdomain

Using .htaccess I'm looking to remove https and make it https on all subdomains because it's returning a browser error as I don't have an SSL certificate for the subodomains.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you don't have a certificate, you cannot provide HTTPS. There is nothing you need to do. If a request comes in via HTTPS, you *do* have a certificate and the user has already ignored the fact that your certificate might be invalid or not issued by a trusted CA.

Answer (score 0):

You need a **Wildcard SSL certificate** to secure all sub-domains of website. Wildcard SSL certificates allow the management of multiple sub domains on a single domain with a single SSL certificate.

If you don’t have or have a normal SSL certificate, then you can’t provide HTTPS to sub-domains, so I suggest you to **buy a New Wildcard** SSL certificate and then **generate CSR (Code Signing Request) and install** it on your server.

If you are looking for cheap price, then buy it from the third party reseller. They are providing cheaper pricing then vendors. It’s my own experience. Third party reseller provides certificates from top brands with same quality.